# website looking for font files in the wrong place

Tags: css, fonts, webserver, font-face

I'm trying to get a wingding style of font to work on a webserver but it's always looking for the files in the wrong place.

My file system looks like this:

```
/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012
|
|--index.html
|--/css
    |--global.css
    |--/fonts
       |--font.woff
```

I have the @font-face declaration as such:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Pictos';
src: url("/fonts/font-web.eot");
src:local('☺'), url("/fonts/font-web.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/font-web.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fonts/font-web.svg#webfontIyfZbseF") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

It works fine locally, but when I check it on the server it's looking for the font files:

example.com/fonts/pictos.woff
example.com/fonts/pictos.woff

when the website is located at:

http://his.unhcr.org/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012/
and
http://twine.unhcr.org/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012/

It works fine locally if I change the url to ("fonts/font-web.eot") but on the server it starts looking for the file at:

example.com/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012/css/global.css/fonts/pictos-web.woff/

Why does it change from looking at the root to trying to find it in css/global.css/fonts/pictos-web.woff?

(i had to use example.com because my reputation is low, but you supplement it either twine.unhcr.org or his.unhcr.org)

some other facts: twine.unhcr.org/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012/ is redirected from his.unhcr.org/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012/

I don't have access to the server so I'm trying to use a htaccess file in xampp to redirect my local files.

Comment: try '/css/fonts/font-web.woff'?

Comment: From what you've posted it seems fine. As long as your css file is definitely in the css directory. You could try making your path "/css/fonts/" and see if that helps.

Comment: The problem with that is the webpage is located at:
http://website.org/projectsite/index.html
so the css files aren't located at 
http://website.org/css/fonts/font.woff

Comment: Please do not use domain names like website.org as dummy names. Use the reserved names like example.com, or (betterr) use real, working URLs.

Comment: There is little hope of getting the problem solved unless you give some real facts. I’m afraid the URL of the page is needed. In a comment, you refer to redirection, which may well mess things up.

Comment: here is the urls to the page:
http://his.unhcr.org/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012/
and
http://twine.unhcr.org/phhiv_asia_workshop_2012/

Answer (score 1):

try using the absolute path to the font files, ie. http://www.mydomain.com/css/fonts/font-web.woff

Comment: It's for a client and they don't want to use absolute paths. Especially since the page that is causing me errors is also redirected onto another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `./fonts/font-web.woff`